# javascript skips validation form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have html running javascript after form,

```
form name="mortgage" method="post" action=" "onsubmit="return completeFormValidation();">
```

And javascript code for validation,

```
function completeFormValidation() {

location();


} // End of completeFormValidation

function location(){



var numradio = document.mortgage.propLocation.length;
var selected="";

for(var i=0; i < numradio; i++){

    if(document.mortgage.propLocation[i].checked == true){
        selected += "Selected radio item " + i;

    }
}

if(selected == ""){

    document.getElementById("reserved").innerHTML = "<p> none radio selected </P>";
    return false;

}

}
```

The code works perfectly fine in dream weaver but in browsers doesn't seem to work instead it will submit even if radio buttons aren't selected. Please help me out thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are not returning the "FALSE/TRUE" value from **completeFormValidation** function.. And **Change the name of the function Location is reserved by JavaScript.**

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/632SY/3/)

```
function completeFormValidation() {

return my_location();

}
```

its always better to return the value from location **true OR false**

you can modify your **my_location()** as below

```
function my_location(){

var numradio = document.mortgage.propLocation.length;
var selected="";

for(var i=0; i < numradio; i++){

    if(document.mortgage.propLocation[i].checked == true){
        selected += "Selected radio item " + i;

    }
}

if(selected == ""){

    document.getElementById("reserved").innerHTML = "<p> none radio selected </P>";
    return false;

}
else{
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: so how should i fix it?

Comment: check now your `completeFormValidation` function return the value received from `location` method

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
function completeFormValidation() {

location();

} // End of completeFormValidation
```

by

```
function completeFormValidation() {

return location();

} // End of completeFormValidation
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `location` function. `location` is a native property of the `window` object and can not be redefined.

Comment: thank you! that worked! how can i find the list for native properties in javascript so i dont make this mistake again?